# NodeJS - Getting error "Can't set headers after they are sent"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node and I am building rest node API.I am using express for HTTP and JWT for authentication. Whenever I request /node/me with header 'x-auth'.
It's giving error which is given below. I have set up middleware in /node/me
which query mogodb database. It finds user using header 'x-auth'

**server.js:**

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if (env === "development") {
    process.env.PORT = 3000;
    process.env.MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp';
} else if (env === "test") {
    process.env.PORT = 3000;
    process.env.MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoAppTest';
}
var _ = require('lodash');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
var app = express();

var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {Todo} = require('./models/todo');
var {User} = require('./models/user');
const {authenticate} = require('./middleware/authenticate');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/users/me',authenticate,(req,res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
});
module.exports = {
    app,
    env
}

app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`server is running ${port}`);
});
```

**authenticate.js:**

```
const {User} = require('./../models/user');
var authenticate = (req,res,next) => {
var token = req.header('x-auth');
User.findByToken(token).then((doc) => {
    if (!doc) {
       res.status(401).send('doc is not found');
    }
    req.token = token;
    req.user = doc;
    next();
}).catch((e) => {
    res.status(401).send(e);
});
```

I am getting this error about headers

```
 Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Yash\Desktop\node-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Yash\Desktop\node-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:164:12)
    at app.get (C:\Users\Yash\Desktop\node-api\server\server.js:254:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Yash\Desktop\node-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Yash\Desktop\node-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at User.findByToken.then (C:\Users\Yash\Desktop\node-api\server\middleware\authenticate.js:19:2)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change to this:

```
if(!doc) {
    res.status(401).send('doc is not found');
} else {
    req.token = token;
    req.user = doc;
    next();
}
```

The reason is after the if inside code is executed the flow continues independently if you are sending a response because it is just a function call. So you are executing the error code and after that you are executing the success code, I mean the next function like if the doc exists and at the moment of the `next()` execution the response has been sent.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can only send one response with express. If you follow the series of events in your Authenticate middleware you'll discover that you are sending a response with:

```
res.status(401).send('doc is not found');
```

and then calling `next()`. When you call next it passes control over to the next middleware, which then sends:

```
res.send(req.user);
```

Cut the `next()` out of the loop when the request fails with something like:

```
if(!doc){
    res.status(401).send('doc is not found');
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must export authenticate. And add return

```
if(!doc) {
    res.status(401).send('doc is not found');
    return;
}
```

or add else

```
if(!doc) {
    res.status(401).send('doc is not found');
  } else {
      req.token = token;
      req.user = doc;
      next();
}
```